# Error InvalidPrivateLinkData while creating Private Endpoint for Azure Bot Service using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-bot-service

Trying to create Private endpoint for Azure Bot Service Using terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
    
  name = azurerm_bot_service_azure_bot.bot_service.name    
  location            = example.location
  resource_group_name = example.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = ...         
    private_dns_zone_ids = ["/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/privatelink.directline.botframework.com"]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = ...    
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_bot_service_azure_bot.bot_service.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = "botServices"
  }
}
```

Getting error:

```
Error: creating Private Endpoint (Subscription: "YYYY"
Resource Group Name: "ZZZ"
Private Endpoint Name: "zzzz"): performing CreateOrUpdate: unexpected status 400 with error: InvalidPrivateLinkData: Call to Microsoft.BotService/botServices failed. Error message: Invalid groupId(s) present in request

  with module.bot_service.azurerm_private_endpoint.private_endpoint["YYYY"],
  on ../modules/LandingZone/AIKM/bot_service/main.tf line 28, in resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint":
  28: resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
```

I belive I am providing correct sub resource name. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to overcome the Error **InvalidPrivateLinkData** while creating Private Endpoint for Azure Bot Service using terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error typically indicates a problem with the `subresource_names` specified in the `private_service_connection` block of your Terraform configuration. The `subresource_names` should match the subresource that you are trying to connect to via the private endpoint.

For Azure Bot Service, the correct subresource name might be different from `"botServices"`. Make sure you use the valid name as shown in the attachment below.

[image]

Depending on the configuration, make sure you use the appropriate subresource from the available options.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "demovk-rg"
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "demovksnet"
  virtual_network_name = "demovkvnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_bot_channels_registration" "example_bot" {
  name                = "demovk_bot_service"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "F0"

  microsoft_app_id = "8edf0b46-dc33-4385-8fb5-ac6d53ff8db1"
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
  name                = "${azurerm_bot_channels_registration.example_bot.name}-endpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name = "demovk-dns-zone-group"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [
      "/subscriptions/[Subscription_ID]/resourceGroups/demovk-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/demovksep.com"
    ]
  }

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "demovk-service-connection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_bot_channels_registration.example_bot.id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["Bot"]  # Adjust this based on the Azure Bot Service subresource
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]